# Applying <p:commandButton> style to <p:commandLink> because I basically need <p:commandButton target="_blank">

Tags: jsf, primefaces, commandlink, commandbutton

Does anyone know how to put the same styles from the commandbutton to all commandlinks?

I want that all links appear like this (overriding links styles and using the button styles):

**A normal button:**
[image]

**A hovered button:**
[image]

**A pressed button:**
[image]

My current primefaces theme is **start**

Comment: Applying `<p:commandButton>` style on `<h:link>` or `<a>` is understandable and reasonable, but on `<p:commandLink>`? Why not just make it a `<p:commandButton>` directly?

Comment: @BalusC Because I need to open a new tab in the browser to show a pdf file and <p:commandButton> doesn't have the target attribute

Comment: <p:commandButton> doesn't work but <h:commandButton> does. Another way is to put the <p:commandButton> styles to all <h:commandButton> components. Can you help me do some of these things, please

Comment: Using `<h:form target="_blank">` or `<p:commandButton ajax="false" onclick="form.target='_blank'">` isn't an option?

Comment: Excellent, the second one was selected. Thanks @BalusC, you can put this comment as answer to select it immediately

Comment: I posted an answer and updated the question's title to reflect the concrete functional requirement better.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As per the comments, just stick to `<p:commandButton>` and use an alternate solution to solve the initial functional requirement of the need to open the PDF file download in a new window without explicitly setting the `<h:form target>` (which would affect all of form's command buttons/links).

```
<p:commandButton ... ajax="false" onclick="form.target='_blank'">
```

This ends up in less CSS pain.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC. As always you are the greatest one

Comment: @BalusC, Perfect solution for my issue, I don't know how many more times I need to say 'Your awesome' in rest of my JSF life.

Answer (score 3):

You can use style sheets used in command button for command link.

```
  <p:commandLink style="padding: .3em 1em;" styleClass="ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only ui-button-text ui-c" ajax="false" value="Download as Excel" download="#{salaryCycleController.current}.xls" onclick="return ExcellentExport.excel(this, 'tbl', 'Sheet1');" ></p:commandLink>
```

I was compelled to use p:commandLink as p:commandButton did not support the download attribute.